# Drag to scroll outside of element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I've made a scrollable container but there's a problem with how it behaves when the mouse pointer leaves the element box while pressed. When it happens scrolling goes in the opposite direction from what I want in Firefox and stops in Edge. Scrolling in Firefox seems to be the native behaviour of the browser.
Is it possible to make it work the same way it does when the cursor is over the element?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/tinsoldat-the-lessful/pen/qBmmqeG)

HTML

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

JS

```
import React from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/react"
import ReactDOM from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/react-dom"

const HelloWorld = () => <h1>Hello, World!</h1>

const Scrollable = props => {
  const ref = React.useRef()
  const [scroll, setScroll] = React.useState({ isScrolling: false, clientX: 0 })
  
  const onMouseDown = e => {
    setScroll({ ...scroll, isScrolling: true, clientX: e.clientX })
  }

  const onMouseUp = () => {
    setScroll({ ...scroll, isScrolling: false })
  }

  const onMouseMove = e => {
    const { clientX } = scroll
    if (scroll.isScrolling) {
      const dx = e.clientX - clientX
      const scrollLeft = ref.current.scrollLeft - dx

      if (scrollLeft < 0 || scrollLeft > ref.current.scrollLeftMax) return

      ref.current.scrollLeft = scrollLeft
      setScroll({ ...scroll, clientX: e.clientX })
    }
  }  
  
  return(
    <div className="scrollable" ref={ref}
      style={{'overflow-x': 'auto', width: '200px', 'margin-left': '100px' }}
      onMouseDown={onMouseDown}
      onMouseUp={onMouseUp}
      onMouseMove={onMouseMove}
    >
      {props.children}
    </div>
  )
}
      
ReactDOM.render(<Scrollable><div style={{ height: '100px', width: '1000px', background: 'red' }}></div></Scrollable>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Comment: Kindly provide executable and reproducible code, preferably in a codepen/jsfiddle/codesandbox.